# CheckedChanged Event Not Firing In Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dynamic

I have a gridview in which I have manually generated a column for checkboxes as a `HeaderTemplate` as below

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDB" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" OnRowDataBound="gvDB_RowDataBound" <asp:TemplateField>
<HeaderTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectHeader" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelectHeader_CheckedChanged" runat="server"/>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelect_CheckedChanged1" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And `OnRowDataBound` I'm dynamically generating controls and adding it to the each row

```
e.Row.Cells[rowIndex].Controls.Add(control);
```

And they are binding to the columns as expected.But my `chkSelectHeader_CheckedChanged` `chkSelect_CheckedChanged1` events are not firing.

Page Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
      AddTemplatesToGrid();
    }
    BindDataToGridView();
 }




 public void AddTemplatesToGrid()
 {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    foreach (Employees emp in EmployeesList)
    {
    TemplateField tfield = new TemplateField();
    tfield.HeaderText = emp.Name;
    gvDataEntry.Columns.Add(tfield);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Dont add controls in `RowDataBound`. Dynamically created controls must be created on every postback, but `RowDataBound` is only triggered if the grid gets databound. Use `RowCreated` for that purpose.

Comment: I have done on `RowCreated` yet the events are not firing @TimSchmelter

Comment: maybe you are databinding the grid on every postback(show your `Page_Load`). You should do that only if necessary.

Comment: I have updated with some code, refer once @TimSchmelter

Comment: You haven't shown the code where you assign the datasource and call `gvDataEntry.DataBind()`.

Comment: There it is and I'm adding different controls to each row(based on some conditions) and binding them individually @TimSchmelter

Comment: And there is your problem. You call `BindDataToGridView` on every postback which will discard events.

Comment: @MitatKoyuncu: a `GridView` has no `AutoPostBack` property

Answer (score 0):

You call `BindDataToGridView` on every postback which will discard events.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
      AddTemplatesToGrid();
    }
    BindDataToGridView();
 }
```

Include `BindDataToGridView()` in the `!Page.IsPostBack`-check.

Comment: ok, but `RowCreated` Event is being called every time I check the checkbox, how to avoid it @Tim Schmelter

Comment: @Learner: what's the problem with `RowCreated`? You have to create all controls on every postback, but you don't have to DataBind the grid on every postback.

Comment: I meant to say,the event is being fired up for every checkbox selection, how to stop it from calling when checkbox checked

Comment: So you want to disable the `CheckBox` when it was checked once? You can use `((CheckBox)sender).Enabled = false;`

Comment: I don't want the `RowCreated` to be firing for every`chkSelectHeader_CheckedChanged` event

Comment: @Learner Try to Check if `Sender` is from Checkbox or Not , If its from Checkbox dont enter into the `RowCreated`

Comment: I have tried this `if (!(sender is CheckBox))` but it is reurning always false,It is not from checkbox @Webruster

Comment: @Learner Where u are checking this condition??

Comment: In my `RowCreated` event @Webruster